# SQL Server: Group by sum of values after inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a query pulling charge data from our electronic record system.  I'm trying to combine the data by payer type (fee for service or FFS vs. Capitated payers).

My query is:

```
select pm.last_name, (case when ml.mstr_list_item_desc = 'Capitated' then 'cap' else 'ffs' end) as Charge, SUM(case when begin_date_of_service >= '20150901' and begin_date_of_service  < '20151001' then amt else 0 end) as Total_Charge_Sep15
from charges c
inner join provider_mstr pm ON c.rendering_id = pm.provider_id
inner join patient_encounter pe ON pe.enc_id = c.source_id
inner join payer_mstr py on py.payer_id = pe.cob1_payer_id
inner join mstr_lists ml on ml.mstr_list_item_id = py.financial_class
where c.begin_date_of_service >= '20140101' and c.begin_date_of_service  < '20160101' 
group by pm.last_name, ml.mstr_list_item_desc
order by last_name
```

What I get from this query is:

```
Person A       ffs    ChargeTotal

Person A       cap    ChargeTotal

Person A       ffs    ChargeTotal

Person A       ffs    ChargeTotal

Person A       ffs    ChargeTotal
```

Each FFS is translated from a specific payer (Blue Cross, medicare, etc).
I'd like the query to combine those FFS charges into one category for all FFS payers instead of separating them out.  Since there is only one 'Capitated' payer, that only gets listed once.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show your desire output.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need use keyword `distinct`

so you write it like this

```
select **distinct** pm.last_name .... .... ... 
from charges c
....
....
```

and will get

```
Person A       ffs    ChargeTotal
Person A       cap    ChargeTotal
```

Comment: ahh, can't believe I missed that.  Thanks!

Comment: please remember accept the answer if help you with your problem.